# select data based on multiple attributes d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have a grid represented using d3 and svg. I am trying to select the neighbouring (adjacent) tiles to any specific tile on the grid. the tiles are accessed via their x and y coordinates on the grid.
What I have feels fairly messy, and doesn't do exactly what I want, I don't want the clicked tile to be selected, or the tiles diagonal to it.

```
var w = 960,
    h = 500,
    z = 20,
    x = w / z,
    y = h / z;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);

svg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(d3.range(x * y))
  .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("width", z)
    .attr("height", z)
    .attr("clicked", false)
    .attr('x', horizontalpos)
    .attr('y', verticalpos)
    .on("click", test)
    .style("stroke", "rgb(6,120,155)")
    .style("stroke-width", 2)
    .style("fill", "rgb(255, 255, 255)")

function translate(d) {
  return "translate(" + (d % x) * z + "," + Math.floor(d / x) * z + ")";
}


function verticalpos(d) {
  return ((d % x) * z);
}

function horizontalpos(d) {
  return (Math.floor(d / x) * z );
 }

function test(){
  var d = d3.selectAll("[x='40']").filter("[y='40']");
  d3.selectAll("[x=" + "'"+ (parseInt(d.attr("x")) +20).toString() +"'" +"],[x=" + "'"+ (parseInt(d.attr("x")) -20).toString() +"'" +"],"+ "[x=" + "'"+ (parseInt(d.attr("x"))).toString() +"'" +"]")
    .filter("[y=" + "'"+ (parseInt(d.attr("y"))).toString() +"'" +"],[y=" + "'"+ (parseInt(d.attr("y")) +20).toString() +"'" +"]"+",[y=" + "'"+ (parseInt(d.attr("y")) -20).toString() +"'" +"]")
    .transition()
    .style("fill", "black"); 

}
```

jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/wkencq2w/15/

What I'm wondering is - Is there a way to select the data via two attributes, like this:

```
d3.select("[x='40'], [y='40']")
```

This does not work for me, but the logic behind it is how I would like to select the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to fix this problem using filter:

```
function test(d){
  var x = d3.select(this);
  var x1 = (parseInt(x.attr("x")) +20);
  var x2 = (parseInt(x.attr("x")) -20);
  var y1 = (parseInt(x.attr("y")) +20);
  var y2 = (parseInt(x.attr("y")) -20);
var f = d3.selectAll("rect")[0].filter(function(d){
  //left rect
    if (d3.select(d).attr("x") == x1 && d3.select(d).attr("y") == parseInt(x.attr("y")))
    return true;
  //right rect  
    if (d3.select(d).attr("x") == x2 && d3.select(d).attr("y") == parseInt(x.attr("y")))
    return true;
  //bottom rect  
    if (d3.select(d).attr("y") == y1 && d3.select(d).attr("x") == parseInt(x.attr("x")))
    return true;
  //top rect  
    if (d3.select(d).attr("y") == y2 && d3.select(d).attr("x") == parseInt(x.attr("x")))
    return true;

  return false;
});
//select all filtered and make their fill black
d3.selectAll(f).transition().delay(100).style("fill", "black");

}
```

Working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/wsn2mg2z/1/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! I have been playing around with this and searching for options for ages. New to javascript and d3 so I appreciate the help.

Comment: @user3636636 Both, the question as well as this answer have mixed up the orientation of the grid. According to `x`and `y` the squares are supposed to form a rectangle which is horizontally aligned to fully fill the viewport. As it is drawn now, however, it is positioned upright clipping it at the bottom of the SVG, thus giving it a square outline. Although this can easily be cured by swapping formulas in `verticalpos()` and `horizontalpos()` you might want to have a look at my [answer](/a/34611132/4235784) which avoids this issue by relying more on data binding and D3's inner workings.

Answer (score 3):

Because it's D3, I won't do this based on calculations of positions but rather on data binding. This will simplify matters a lot and reduce the amount and the complexity of your code. One possible way might be to define a two-dimensional array of objects having x and y properties which is then bound to a D3 selection:

```
var grid = d3.range(y).map(function(dy) {
  return d3.range(x).map(function(dx) {
    return {x: dx, y: dy};
  });
});

var g = svg.selectAll("g")
    .data(grid)
  .enter().append("g")                 // Group each row's rects in a svg:g
    .selectAll("rect")                 // Do a nested selection
    .data(function(d) { return d; })   // Bind the sub-array for this row
```

The part which benefits most from this approach is your `test()` function which may now act on the data bound to each rect rather than having to get attribute values and doing calculation with them.

```
function test(d) {
  var clicked = d3.select(this).datum();   // Object bound to the rect.
  d3.selectAll("rect").filter(function(d) {
    // Do the filtering based on data rather than on positions.
    return d.x === clicked.x && Math.abs(d.y - clicked.y) === 1 ||
           d.y === clicked.y && Math.abs(d.x - clicked.x) === 1;
  })
  .transition()
  .style("fill", "black"); 
}
```

Have a look at this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wkencq2w/17/) for a full example.

Comment: Thanks for the help, this looks a lot more clean and efficient than my approach

Answer (score 3):

You can select data via two attributes just by putting them together e.g. [x='40'][y='40']. This together with the , css operator allows the generation of a css selection string that gives you what you asked for.

```js
var w = 960,
    h = 500,
    z = 20,
    x = w / z,
    y = h / z;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);

svg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(d3.range(x * y))
  .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("width", z)
    .attr("height", z)
    .attr("clicked", false)
    .attr('x', horizontalpos)
    .attr('y', verticalpos)
    .on("click", test)
    .style("stroke", "rgb(6,120,155)")
    .style("stroke-width", 2)
    .style("fill", "rgb(255, 255, 255)")
    
function translate(d) {
  return "translate(" + (d % x) * z + "," + Math.floor(d / x) * z + ")";
}


function verticalpos(d) {
  return ((d % x) * z);
}

function horizontalpos(d) {
  return (Math.floor(d / x) * z );
 }
 
function test(d) {
  x = parseInt(d3.select(this).attr("x"));
  y = parseInt(d3.select(this).attr("y"));
  var selector = ""
  for (var dx=-20;dx<=20;dx+=20) {
   for (var dy=-20;dy<=20;dy+=20) {
      selector += "[x='"+ (x + dx) +"'][y='"+ (y + dy) +"'],"
    }
  }
  // cut off the final extraneous comma
  selector = selector.substring(0, selector.length - 1);
  d3.selectAll(selector)
    .transition()
    .style("fill", "black"); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Or if you just want a cross without the centre as you describe in the question you could do this...

```js
var w = 960,
    h = 500,
    z = 20,
    x = w / z,
    y = h / z;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);

svg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(d3.range(x * y))
  .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("width", z)
    .attr("height", z)
    .attr("clicked", false)
    .attr('x', horizontalpos)
    .attr('y', verticalpos)
    .on("click", test)
    .style("stroke", "rgb(6,120,155)")
    .style("stroke-width", 2)
    .style("fill", "rgb(255, 255, 255)")
    
function translate(d) {
  return "translate(" + (d % x) * z + "," + Math.floor(d / x) * z + ")";
}


function verticalpos(d) {
  return ((d % x) * z);
}

function horizontalpos(d) {
  return (Math.floor(d / x) * z );
 }
 
function test(d) {
  x = parseInt(d3.select(this).attr("x"));
  y = parseInt(d3.select(this).attr("y"));
  var selector = ""
  var deltas = [[-20, 0], [20, 0], [0, 20], [0, -20]];
  for (var i=0;i < deltas.length;i++) {
    selector += "[x='"+ (x + deltas[i][0]) +"'][y='"+ (y + deltas[i][1]) +"'],"
  }
  
  // cut off the final extraneous comma
  selector = selector.substring(0, selector.length - 1);
  d3.selectAll(selector)
    .transition()
    .style("fill", "black"); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```